# React router is not opening multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, router

My react router is not opening my news and photos pages. When they open it's supposed to display the header file on each pages. When I try to open the news page (localhost:8080/news) I get a 404 page not found error message in my node command prompt.

[My GitHub repository](https://github.com/andrew2ec/react-countryNews)

```
var React = require('react');

var ReactRouter = require('react-router');

var Router = ReactRouter.Router;

var Route = ReactRouter.Route;


var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

var Header = require('./components/Header.jsx');

var News = require('./components/News.jsx');

var Photos = require('./components/Photos.jsx');


var Routes = (

    <Router history={browserHistory}>

        <Route path="/" component={Header}>

            <Route path="news" component={News} />

            <Route path="photos" component={Photos} />

        </Route>

    </Router>

);

module.exports = Routes;
```

Comment: Please show relevant code *here*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick answer of what you can do to your main.js file. There's probably better ways you could structure your code. I would suggest taking a closer look at more React examples around the Internet.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Routes = require('./Routes.jsx');
var Header = require('./components/Header.jsx');

var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Routes />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('switch'));
```

I noticed your code seems to have a lot of duplicate files for a .js and a .jsx. You know you only need one or the other, right?

Comment: So would deleting the js files did the issue?

Comment: Wait. My bad. I missed the 404 part. That's just to fix the issue where your header wouldn't be showing up on all of your pages. Let me look again.

Comment: Well it looks like part of your problem is that you should be doing a React.createClass on your Routes.jsx file as well just like any other component. But ultimately, you don't need a .js file for every .jsx file. From what I'm seeing they are doing exactly the same thing just written in two different ways. I would choose the JSX formatted files over the other mainly because it's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I would suggest looking up some simple react examples on github. That way you can see how other people structured their code.

Comment: But I want the header to show up on each page. I'll delete the js files.

Comment: The header should show on every page by the example I posted above.

Comment: Is there a main.jsx version?

Comment: Seeing that I'm really using jsx.

Comment: I set up the Main component right inside of your main.js file. You don't need a main.jsx file.

Comment: The extension doesn't have to be jsx by the way. Depending on how you have your build runner you're using (gulp, webpack, grunt, etc.) the extensions can be js or jsx and have jsx within them. I personally don't use the jsx extension at all.

Comment: Ugh... can't edit that comment. I meant to say... Depending on how you have your build runner configured...

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was using react-router v3.0 so I uninstalled it and installed the 2.8.1 version. It still displays the # (ie. localhost/#/news) but it's close enough. Thanks for your help.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;

var useRouterHistory = ReactRouter.useRouterHistory;
var createHashHistory = require('react-router/node_modules/history/lib/createHashHistory');
var appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({
queryKey:false
});

var Header = require('./components/Header.jsx');
var News = require('./components/News.jsx');
var Photos = require('./components/Photos.jsx');

var Routes = (
<Router history={appHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Header}>
        <Route path="/news" component={News} />
        <Route path="/photos" component={Photos} />
    </Route>
</Router>
);
module.exports = Routes;
```